# Merging two table based on column headers in R

Tags: r

Would like to merge two tables based on the column heading:

So i would like to merge TableA and TableB with kind of left join and want a output as mentioned in OutputTable.

To explain it further OutputTable should be like:

1) Pertain all the columns header from TableA

2) Paste the data which were present in TableB with similar columns.

3) Column of TableA which were not present in TableB would have data as 0

```
TableA <- data.frame(
  action =  c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
  actor  =  c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
  also   =  c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
  anim   =  c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
  appear =  c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1))

TableB <- data.frame(
  action = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  actor  = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  also   = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
  bear   = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
  book   = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  appear = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1))

OutputTable <- data.frame(
  action = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  actor  = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  also   = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
  anim   = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  appear = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1))
```

[image]

So

[image]

Final

[image]

Comment: explained it further, can you please check and let me know if it requires further explanation.

Comment: Can you please let me know where you are finding the disconnect. okay so in the final output i want the column header of TableA and the data of TableB for the columns who have similar column name and for the rest columns which do not have the matching would be getting data as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create two indexes based with `intersect` and `setdiff`

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(TableA), names(TableB))
nm2 <- setdiff(names(TableA), names(TableB))
```

Create a new dataset by subsetting the 'TableB' columns that are common with 'TableA', Set the columns that are different in 'TableA' with 0

```
df3 <- TableB[nm1]
df3[nm2] <- 0
df3
#   action actor also appear anim
#1      1     0    1      0    0
#2      0     1    0      0    0
#3      0     0    0      1    0
#4      0     1    1      0    0
#5      0     0    1      1    0
```

---

If the `order` of columns is important,

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(TableA, TableB, .id = 'grp') %>% 
      select_if(~ !is.na(.[1])) %>%
      filter(grp == 2) %>%
      select(-grp) %>%
      mutate_all(replace_na, 0)
#    action actor also anim appear
#1      1     0    1    0      0
#2      0     1    0    0      0
#3      0     0    0    0      1
#4      0     1    1    0      0
#5      0     0    1    0      1
```

Comment: Nice solution but the column orders should not be changed.

Comment: Here anim is coming on last position. so can you please share your views for maintaing the similar column position mentioned in TableA

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using library gtools

```
library(gtools)

output <- smartbind(TableA,TableB)
str(output)
output[is.na(output)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use `merge`. First you would have to create a key in order to join the data on (like in SQL). For example if the first two columns are those which interest you, you could do:

```
colsofinterest <- 1:2
TableA$id <- apply(TableA[,colsofinterest], 1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse=""))
TableB$id <- apply(TableB[,colsofinterest], 1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse=""))
res3 <- merge(TableA, TableB, by="id", all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
```

However to get to your desired output I wouldn't use a join, but simply add a column.

```
res2 <- TableB[,c(1:3,4)]
res2$anim <- 0
res2
  action actor also bear anim
1      1     0    1    0    0
2      0     1    0    1    0
3      0     0    0    1    0
4      0     1    1    0    0
5      0     0    1    1    0
```

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear this is very generic things by calling the indexing, however, i am looking for the solution without any manual intervention like indexing.